# How can I use jqGrid to view static json?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to make a nice view of a static json file with jqgrid and am total beginner at javascript.  I made a simplified file to start with, but when I look at the logs, jqGrid is trying to do a query on the server.  Is it possible to use jqGrid with static json?

My test file:

http://schwehr.org/NGDC_DEMs.json

And I see this in the logs:

http://schwehr.org/NGDC_DEMs.json?_search=false&nd=1344908237004&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc

Which is not going to work.  Is it possible to easily do all this just in the browser?

The file is really boring:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Elfin Cove MHHW",
        "demid": 4230,
    },
    {
        "title": "Astoria V2",
        "demid": 4090,
    },
    {
        "title": "South Padre Island",
        "demid": 3984,
    },
]
```

Thanks!
-kurt

Answer (score 8):

Two ways to solve this problem.

First make your json look like this

```
var data = {
            "page": "1",
            "records": "3",
            "rows": [
                { "id": "83123a", Name: "Name 1"},//give your column names here
                { "id": "83432a", Name: "Name 3"},
                { "id": "83566a", Name: "Name 2" }
            ]
        },
```

Now use use datatype: "jsonstring" and datastr: data. In the case you need to add additional parameter jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }.

The second way is to use datatype: "local" and data: data.rows. In the case the [localReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#array_data) will be used to read the data from the data.rows array. The default localReader can read the data.

Your demos for the questions are [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AddJsonData.htm) and [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AddJsonData1.htm).

Comment: Thanks much for the example!  So you really have to structure the data to match a jqGrid model?  Meaning that I will want to pull the full json and restructure?  e.g. this is the actual static json that I'd like to build a table for: http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/eds/json/NGDC_DEMs.json

Comment: I had a look on your json data, you can ignore these two "page and "records" parameter, as your json data is in "record" variable and here it is in "rows" variable, so without changing your json you can add jsonReader: {root:"records", repeatitems: false }, to the code, now generally root:"rows", we specify this value but your data is in records, so you can go with this. get it?

Comment: and i'm hoping if this works for you then you will mark it as answer?